# Power steering leak in 82 GMC truck

Tags: power-steering, gmc, power-steering-fluid

I have a 1982 GMC K1500. This junction where the steering column connects to this other part is moist and occasionally drips a reddish fluid. What is this other part called and what is involved in fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: That's a leaking input shaft seal on your power steering gearbox. Usually replace with a rebuilt unit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the part you are talking about is called a "rag joint". It softens the feel between the steering wheel and the steering box.

That isn't what's leaking, though. It appears (from the one photo) the problem is the seal from the steering shaft on the steering gear box. You could possibly replace it, but if time is considered money, you'd be better off replacing the entire steering gear.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I see from Moab's post below that the gear box is more expensive but I'd imagine significantly easier to install.

Comment: I don't know about "easier", but I think a lot less time consuming. There are several parts which are *tough* to get off, so a bit of a trade off. Thing is, you have to remove quite a few of those same components to get to the seal as well. Thing is, after you've replaced the seal, you still have an old steering box which is most likely worn out ... which could be why the seal is worn out in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Power steering Gear input shaft seal, they make a kit just for that but is tricky to install, might be better off installing a reman PS Gear.

[See kit Edelman 8525](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/chevrolet,1982,c10+pickup,5.7l+350cid+v8,1030824,steering,steering+gear+input+shaft+seal,7353)

[See reman gear Cardone 277522](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/chevrolet,1982,c10+pickup,5.7l+350cid+v8,1030824,steering,steering+gear,7416)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the links. Is there a good writeup or book that would walk me through the process of doing this myself? I assume an alignment would probably be needed afterward?

Comment: Also, I'm told this truck has something called hydroboost where the power brakes run off of the PS pump. Will those reman pumps that you linked to be OK in light of this information or do I need a differnet one?

Comment: You will need a couple of somewhat specialty tool to replace the steering box. You will need tubing wrenches to remove the lines, a pitman arm puller to remove the steering arm that attaches to the steering box. a tierod breaking tool . You will also need a "large" breaker bar (pitman arm to steering box nut is torqued to about 180ftlbs).

Comment: No alignment needed. "Will those reman pumps that you linked to be OK in light of this information or do I need a different one? " Gear box is the same for both.